# Having trouble getting VBA to edit existing hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba

So I am running a macro that archives an accounting log into an archive folder, after it is archived the macro clears a column on multiple sheets to clear the accounting log. For some reason when I first ran this macro, everything worked fine but every hyperlink that was linked to a folder on the server became corrupted. The final 2 folders are correct but all preceding folders became "../../../../../" when I click on Edit Hyperlink. So it looked like "../../../../../Clients/ClientA/". The archived file has the same "../../" but the links work.

Upon clicking on the link I was prompted with the following error: 'Cannot open the specified file.' But when I edit the file and put folder names instead of "../" then it works fine. I am not sure why this is occurring. But regardless each Hyperlink is on every sheet on Cell G1. So I wrote a macro to fix the links.

```
  Sub hyperUpdate()
  Dim wsHyper As Worksheet, addr As String, lastrow As Long, h As Hyperlink

  lastrow = Worksheets("Auto Archive").Range("A" & Worksheets("Auto 
  Archive").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  For i = 2 To lastrow

  Set wsHyper = Worksheets(Worksheets("Auto Archive").Cells(i, 1).Value)
  wsHyper.Activate
  addr = Worksheets("Auto Archive").Cells(i, 3).Value
  wsHyper.Cells(1, 7).Activate


  Application.ActiveCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address = addr
  MsgBox Application.ActiveCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address

  Next i

  End Sub
```

So The message box said the correct address each time but when i click on edit hyperlink I get the same "../../" and the link still doesn't work. What is a better way to go about this? Thank you

Comment: Excel does love to edit hyperlinks itself ... I had a similar problem. My first "fix" was to store the path to each file or folder in a cell in Excel. Then I put code into the Sheet.Activate event for re-building the hyperlinks - slows noticeably with a few hundred hyperlinks in a sheet. That worked for a while but was less than perfect, so in the end I went for an alternative and abandoned hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid Hyperlinks - store the path to the file in a cell (instead of the hyperlink)

Then something like following in the sheet.selectionchange procedure

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim MinValidRow as long, MaxValidRow as Long, LinkedCol as long

   MinValidRow = 5 ' You Set this to whatever you want
   MaxValidRow = 9 ' You Set this to whatever you want
   LinkedCol   = 2 ' You Set this to whatever you want

   If Sh.Name = "YourSheet" then
      If Target.Column = LinkedCol and Target.Row > MinValidRow and Target.Row<MaxValidrow then
         CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open(Target.Text)
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

You should also move away from the selected cell so it can be selected again by clicking into it and you probably want to prevent someone firing off loads of files by pressing & holding down arrow